# how to transfer file to azure blob storage in chunks without writing to file using python

Tags: python, azure, google-cloud-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to transfer files from google cloud storage to azure blob storage.

Google gives a code snippet to download files to byte variable like so:

```
# Get Payload Data
req = client.objects().get_media(
        bucket=bucket_name,
        object=object_name,
        generation=generation)    # optional
# The BytesIO object may be replaced with any io.Base instance.
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, req, chunksize=1024*1024)
done = False
while not done:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    if status:
        print 'Download %d%%.' % int(status.progress() * 100)
    print 'Download Complete!'
print fh.getvalue()
```

I was able to modify this to store to file by changing the fh object type like so:

```
fh = open(object_name, 'wb')
```

Then I can upload to azure blob storage using `blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path`.

I want to avoid writing to local file on machine doing the transfer.

I gather Google's snippet loads the data into the io.BytesIO() object a chunk at a time.  I reckon I should probably use this to write to blob storage a chunk at a time.

I experimented with reading the whole thing into memory, and then uploading using `put_block_blob_from_bytes`, but I got a memory error (file is probably too big (~600MB).

Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like append blob is a solution here, but `azure-storage-python` doesn't seem to support it yet.

Comment: How is append blob is a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the source codes of [`blobservice.py` for Azure Storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/blobservice.py) and [`BlobReader` for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore#google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobReader), you can try to use the Azure function `blobservice.put_block_blob_from_file` to write the stream from the GCS class `blobreader` has the function `read` as stream, please see below.

[image]

[image]

So refering to the code from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_BlobReader, you can try to do this as below.

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

blob_key = ...
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)

blob_service = BlobService(account_name, account_key)
container_name = ...
blob_name = ...
blobservice.put_block_blob_from_file(container_name, blob_name, blob_reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the SDK source code, something like this could work:

```
from azure.storage.blob import _chunking
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

# See _BlobChunkUploader
class PartialChunkUploader(_chunking._BlockBlobChunkUploader):
    def __init__(self, blob_service, container_name, blob_name, progress_callback = None):
        super(PartialChunkUploader, self).__init__(blob_service, container_name, blob_name, -1, -1, None, False, 5, 1.0, progress_callback, None)

    def process_chunk(self, chunk_offset, chunk_data):
        '''chunk_offset is the integer offset. chunk_data is an array of bytes.'''
        return self._upload_chunk_with_retries(chunk_offset, chunk_data)

blob_service = BlobService(account_name='myaccount', account_key='mykey')

uploader = PartialChunkUploader(blob_service, "container", "foo")
# while (...):
#     uploader.process_chunk(...)
```