# Azure python storage block blob storage is eating all the memory up

Tags: python, azure, memory, storage, ls

I have written a Python script to make an Azure VM automatically built and upload to Azure from KVM, and I'm facing an issue which I can't fix.
As soon as the VM has been built I'm trying to upload the disk to Azure using the Azure Python module, and the issue is that the script is literally eating all the available RAM. I have tried several ways of coding and it always ends with the same result.

```
   block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(vars.az_storage_acc_name, vars.az_sto_key)
    blob = open(args.pool_path + args.name + "-az"+'.vhd', 'r')
    print "Upload {} to Azure Blob service".format(args.name +"-az"+'.vhd')
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream(vars.az_cnt, args.name +"-az"+'.vhd', blob)
```

I have also tried the following :

```
stream = io.open('/path_to_vhd', 'rb')

BlockBlobService.create_blob_from_stream(vars.az_cnt, "test-stream.vhd", stream)
```

No luck, each time the blob creation is initiated but if fails eventually since there is no RAM available.

Do you have a lead which could allow me to achieve this ?

Comment: According to the `print` word in your code, did you use Python 2?

Comment: If you want to use `block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream` method to upload a large file, please notice the variable `MIN_LARGE_BLOCK_UPLOAD_THRESHOLD` for it, you can refer to the reference description for [`BlockBlobService`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.html) to know more about it which I think helps for you.

Comment: Did you set `MIN_LARGE_BLOCK_UPLOAD_THRESHOLD ` variable at other where? or set other variables `MAX_BLOCK_SIZE` and `MAX_SINGLE_PUT_SIZE`? That will change the sdk action.

Comment: I'm actually using Python2. I don't use this variables, but I will since it seems to be the key solution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require holding the entire stream in memory, untill unless you have max RAM size in your machine, this code will not work and at some point give you systemoutofememory exception.

I would recommend you to upload the stream in chunks instead of writing at one go.

Here is a function for uploading stream in chunks

```
def _upload_blob_chunks(blob_service, container_name, blob_name,
                        blob_size, block_size, stream, max_connections,
                        progress_callback, validate_content, lease_id, uploader_class,
                        maxsize_condition=None, if_modified_since=None, if_unmodified_since=None, if_match=None,
                        if_none_match=None, timeout=None,
                        content_encryption_key=None, initialization_vector=None, resource_properties=None):
    encryptor, padder = _get_blob_encryptor_and_padder(content_encryption_key, initialization_vector,
                                                       uploader_class is not _PageBlobChunkUploader)

    uploader = uploader_class(
        blob_service,
        container_name,
        blob_name,
        blob_size,
        block_size,
        stream,
        max_connections > 1,
        progress_callback,
        validate_content,
        lease_id,
        timeout,
        encryptor,
        padder
    )

    uploader.maxsize_condition = maxsize_condition

    # Access conditions do not work with parallelism
    if max_connections > 1:
        uploader.if_match = uploader.if_none_match = uploader.if_modified_since = uploader.if_unmodified_since = None
    else:
        uploader.if_match = if_match
        uploader.if_none_match = if_none_match
        uploader.if_modified_since = if_modified_since
        uploader.if_unmodified_since = if_unmodified_since

    if progress_callback is not None:
        progress_callback(0, blob_size)

    if max_connections > 1:
        import concurrent.futures
        from threading import BoundedSemaphore

        '''
        Ensures we bound the chunking so we only buffer and submit 'max_connections' amount of work items to the executor.
        This is necessary as the executor queue will keep accepting submitted work items, which results in buffering all the blocks if
        the max_connections + 1 ensures the next chunk is already buffered and ready for when the worker thread is available.
        '''
        chunk_throttler = BoundedSemaphore(max_connections + 1)

        executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_connections)
        futures = []
        running_futures = []

        # Check for exceptions and fail fast.
        for chunk in uploader.get_chunk_streams():
            for f in running_futures:
                if f.done():
                    if f.exception():
                        raise f.exception()
                    else:
                        running_futures.remove(f)

            chunk_throttler.acquire()
            future = executor.submit(uploader.process_chunk, chunk)

            # Calls callback upon completion (even if the callback was added after the Future task is done).
            future.add_done_callback(lambda x: chunk_throttler.release())
            futures.append(future)
            running_futures.append(future)

        # result() will wait until completion and also raise any exceptions that may have been set.
        range_ids = [f.result() for f in futures]
    else:
        range_ids = [uploader.process_chunk(result) for result in uploader.get_chunk_streams()]

    if resource_properties:
        resource_properties.last_modified = uploader.last_modified
        resource_properties.etag = uploader.etag

    return range_ids
```

For reference , you can browse below thread

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_upload_chunking.py

Also , there is similar thread for the same type of request

[how to transfer file to azure blob storage in chunks without writing to file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264428/how-to-transfer-file-to-azure-blob-storage-in-chunks-without-writing-to-file-usi)

Alternatively, you can use powershell to upload VHD to vm storage account like below

```
$rgName = "myResourceGroup"
$urlOfUploadedImageVhd = "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myUploadedVHD.vhd"
Add-AzVhd -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Destination $urlOfUploadedImageVhd `
    -LocalFilePath "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Virtual hard disks\myVHD.vhd"
```

Here is the reference for the same

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input.

What I don't get is, in the end what's the difference between

```
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream
```

and

```
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path
```

If it tries to hold everything in RAM ?

Comment: See create_blob_from_* for high level functions that handle the creation and upload of large blobs with
automatic chunking and progress notifications. Basic difference between these 2 is one takes the file path and other takes the already opened stream.If you want to take the benefit of chunk upload, please use MAX_BLOCK_SIZE and MAX_SINGLE_PUT_SIZE Also please refer to this guide https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/azure-storage/latest/azure-storage.pdf

Comment: Browse this pdf and go to page no 24 for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Please accept as an answer if it helped. It will help others who have the same ASK.