# "The source request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit" when copying blobs in azure using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, blob

I am trying to copy a blob from one storage account to another but I am getting the error saying

```
\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code><Message>The source request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit (5000MB).\nRequestId:4bf1c1bc-511e-01292-72883-585cc12333200\nTime:2022-04-25T09:06:27.8203384Z</Message></Error>'
```

In my header, I am using the header type as `BlockBlob` type.

I am trying to copying with two sas URLs... and I am using the version `2020-08-04`

how can I increase the maximum permissible limit?
or
what I can do to copy it?

python code:

```
import requests


url = "https://..."


headers = {"x-ms-blob-type":"BlockBlob","x-ms-date":"Mon, 25 Apr 2022 10:41:12 GMT","x-ms-version":"2020-08-04","x-ms-copy-source":"https:...",}


resp = requests.put(url, headers=headers)

print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.content)
```

here getting status code `409-conflicts`

and here I am using **sas urls**

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written to copy the blobs.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I have added my piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please check if my findings help to fix your issue**:

> The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.

This error comes when you are uploading/copying a file in Azure Storage Account is larger than 4 MB Size and this issue is might be resolved if we copy/transfer the blob files in chunks.

> `<Error<Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code>`

`CannotVerifyCopySource` Error Code is Internal Server Error (500), here mentioned in the [Blob Service Codes Official Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes) that this failure comes if the HTTP request fails within the specified time.

- Make Sure you are copying the block blob from source account to block blob type in destination account.

**According to this [Microsoft Doc of Copy Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob#authorization)**:

- When using Copy Blob, the Shared Access Signature supplied on the request only applies to the destination blob.
- Separate permissions are required for access to the source blob.
- The authorization would have been done with the same key if you used the shared key (Storage Account Key).
- As you're using SAS, you need to append the SAS token in the `x-ms-copy-source` in the request.

**Please refer these workarounds which helps you to resolve this error**:

- [The source request body for synchronous copy is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit (256MB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/656793/az-storage-blob-copy-start-fails-when-files-are-la.html)
- [Transfer to blob storage in chunks using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264428/how-to-transfer-file-to-azure-blob-storage-in-chunks-without-writing-to-file-usi)